# ServiceStack.Redis store objects with timeout and retrieve by key

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack

I'm trying to move from memcached to redis using the ServiceStack.Redis client. I would like to be able to simply check to see if the Redis cache has the items by key and if not add them with an expiration timeout. Then later retrieve them if they exist.

To test this I have created a simple ASP.NET WebApi project and modified the ValuesController with these two methods.

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        using (var redisClient = new RedisClient("localhost"))
        {
            IRedisTypedClient<IEnumerable<SampleEvent>> redis = redisClient.As<IEnumerable<SampleEvent>>();

            if (!redis.ContainsKey("urn:medications:25"))
            {
                var medsWithID25 = new List<SampleEvent>();
                medsWithID25.Add(new SampleEvent() { ID = 1, EntityID = "25", Name = "Digoxin" });
                medsWithID25.Add(new SampleEvent() { ID = 2, EntityID = "25", Name = "Aspirin" });

                redis.SetEntry("urn:medications:25", medsWithID25);
                redis.ExpireIn("urn:medications:25", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
            }

        }

        return new string[] { "1", "2" };
    }

    public SampleEvent Get(int id)
    {
        using (var redisClient = new RedisClient("localhost"))
        {
            IRedisTypedClient<IEnumerable<SampleEvent>> redis = redisClient.As<IEnumerable<SampleEvent>>();
            IEnumerable<SampleEvent> events = redis.GetById("urn:medications:25");

            if (events != null)
            {
                return events.Where(m => m.ID == id).SingleOrDefault();
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to work. The redis.GetById always returns null. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

UPDATE 1:

If I change the line where I get the data to:

```
IEnumerable<SampleEvent> events = redis.GetValue("urn:medications:25");
```

Then I get my objects back but even after the timeout should have removed it.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I think I figured it out. It seems to be a bug with with TypedRedisClient and/or the way keys are being handled.

I'll post my solution here for anyone else having trouble with this simple scenario where I want to use Redis as a persistent cache and don't really care about the extra functionality for Sets, Hashes, etc...

Add the following Extension method:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using ServiceStack.OrmLite;
using ServiceStack.Common;
using ServiceStack.Common.Utils;
using ServiceStack.DesignPatterns.Model;
using ServiceStack.ServiceInterface;
using ServiceStack.CacheAccess;
using ServiceStack.ServiceHost;
using ServiceStack.Redis;

namespace Redis.Extensions
{
    public static class RedisExtensions
    {
        internal static T GetFromCache<T>(this IRedisClient redisClient, string cacheKey,
            Func<T> factoryFn,
            TimeSpan expiresIn)
        {
            var res = redisClient.Get<T>(cacheKey);
            if (res != null)
            {
                redisClient.Set<T>(cacheKey, res, expiresIn);
                return res;
            }
            else
            {
                res = factoryFn();
                if (res != null) redisClient.Set<T>(cacheKey, res, expiresIn);
                return res;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And then I change my test code to this. Obviously this is sloppy and needs refined but at least my tests are working as expected.

```
using ServiceStack.Redis;
using ServiceStack.Redis.Generic;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using Redis.Extensions;

namespace RedisTestsWithBooksleeve.Controllers
{
    public class SampleEvent
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string EntityID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            using (var redisClient = new RedisClient("localhost"))
            {
                if (!redisClient.ContainsKey("Meds25"))
                {

                    redisClient.GetFromCache<IEnumerable<SampleEvent>>("Meds25", () => { 

                        var medsWithID25 = new List<SampleEvent>();
                        medsWithID25.Add(new SampleEvent() { ID = 1, EntityID = "25", Name = "Digoxin" });
                        medsWithID25.Add(new SampleEvent() { ID = 2, EntityID = "25", Name = "Aspirin" });

                        return medsWithID25;

                    }, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                }

            }

            return new string[] { "1", "2" };
        }

        public SampleEvent Get(int id)
        {
            using (var redisClient = new RedisClient("localhost"))
            {
                IEnumerable<SampleEvent> events = redisClient.GetFromCache<IEnumerable<SampleEvent>>("Meds25", () =>
                {

                    var medsWithID25 = new List<SampleEvent>();
                    medsWithID25.Add(new SampleEvent() { ID = 1, EntityID = "25", Name = "Digoxin" });
                    medsWithID25.Add(new SampleEvent() { ID = 2, EntityID = "25", Name = "Aspirin" });

                    return medsWithID25;

                }, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

                if (events != null)
                {
                    return events.Where(m => m.ID == id).SingleOrDefault();
                }
                else
                    return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```